# Setting a 2D PixelArray

Tags: python, pygame

```py
pixel_array[:2,:2] = [[(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)], [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]]
```

> ```
> ValueError: invalid color argument
> ```

Explanation:

I am trying to set a the pixels of a 2D slice of a [`PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html). In the example above, I want to set the top left four pixels. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried pygame.Color instead of tuples, flattening he right hand side, reading the documentation, searching for other posts, etc. No luck.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks for your answer. Posted: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/3542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Pygame issues - Setting a 2D PixelArray #3542](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/3542#issuecomment-1304781288)

---

> You are trying to set a 2D array to a 3D array

Not really in this case. You can't set a 2D array of colours.

Doing:

```py
my_sub_array = my_array[:2, :2]
print("my_sub_array:", my_sub_array)
```

will produce a 2x2 PixelArray of integer colours from a larger array. You can even set one 2x2 section of an array to equal another 2x2 PixelArray section. e.g.:

```py
import pygame

my_surf = pygame.Surface((4, 4))
my_surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
my_surf.fill((255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 1, 1))  # pixel 00
my_surf.fill((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1))  # pixel 10
my_surf.fill((0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1))  # pixel 01
my_surf.fill((255, 255, 255), (1, 1, 1, 1))  # pixel 11

with pygame.pixelarray.PixelArray(my_surf) as my_array:
    my_sub_array = my_array[:2, :2]
    my_array[2:4, 2:4] = my_sub_array
    print("my_array:", my_array)
```

But you can't set a 2x2 section of a larger array specifically to a 2D array of colours (mapped or unmapped).

You CAN set a 2x2 section of a larger array to have each column, or each row, equal the same 2x1 or 1x2 1D array of colours. e.g.:

```py
my_array[:2, :2] = [0, 16777215]
```

or:

```py
my_array[:2, :2] = [(255, 255, 255), (0, 255, 0)]
```

It will happily copy the same 1 dimensional array of colours over and over again - or even the same individual colour to every pixel in a 2x2 sub array:

```py
my_array[:2, :2] = (0, 255, 0)
```

Anyway, the code is very old - dating back to the Pygame 1 era, I guess whoever wrote it overlooked the 2D colours to 2D PixelArray assignment.

If you want to work around it then the easiest way at the minute is just to make another PixelArray at the smaller size, set the pixels of that however you like and then assign it to a 2D (e.g. 3x3) section of the larger PixelArray.